# Truck only miss fires when it gets up to temp

Tags: engine, misfire, truck, gmc, sierra

07 GMC Sierra 1500 5.3 engine - it radom misfires after it warms up. I have changed 1 coil pack, map sensor, plugs, and wires. It only does it after warming up to temperature. What might be the issue.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exact codes are you getting?